# How do i tell my rails program to run on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel

I'm using the mongrel rails server for running my instance of redmine.

Now, it is automatically choosing the development environment as the current environment. How do i tell my rails app that it is supposed to run in production ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
mongrel_rails start -e production
```